# Adding more buttons to a banner, and adjusting the top margin

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using code from bootstraps main site to create a button banner. I would like to know how to add more buttons to this while keeping its width the same. Also other than style="margin-top: 10px;" how can i adjust the banner?

Bootstrap site: http://getbootstrap.com/components/

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-justified">
   <div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Left</button>
  </div>
  <div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Middle</button>
  </div>
  <div class="btn-group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Right</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: bootstrap doesnt have a component called "banner", to what component are you referring? You should be able to create more buttons by just adding more `btn-group` divs with `buttons` inside them to the `btn-group-justified` div

Comment: This is just a button "group". I did what you said and copied the code and it seemed work. Thanks.